# Find phone number attached to data-only sim card

Tags: sim-card

I have 2 data-only sim cards that I use with 4G routers (Huawei E5576-320), and I need to be able to differentiate them. The "phone numbers" attached to the cards should allow me to differentiate them since they are displayed in my contract. Unfortunately, I can't find this information anywhere. I can't think of another way to tell them apart because the bodies of the cards are identical and I don't know which card (of credit-card format) I detached them from.

I checked the router settings but can't find the information anywhere. I also tried to put the sim cards in my phone (Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G) but the sim card manager from the settings app tells me "unknown number".

Is there a way to find this information? Or is there another way I could differentiate them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the data-only SIM cards support SMS? Then you could simply send an SMS containing the phone number to the number itself and see where the SMS is received.

Comment: They unfortunately don't.

Comment: The service provider finally sent me the numbers printed on each card, telling me which one was which. All clear. Thanks for your help Robert.